# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS WWW

Tags: wordpress

Our website platform is wordpress. Our website has www as the preferred version of the domain on Google.

We migrated from http to https. We were able to redirect all http traffic to https www with a redirect code added to the .htaccess file.

But now we have 2 redirects for our domain.

please check this image for the redirects: https://postimg.org/image/9s2dwrrtj/

How do we optimize to have only 1 redirect?

The redirect code we are using is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it really matters, as long as you do *not* put `L` as a tag on the not-last `http` or `www` redirect, the script should carry out both redirects in one pass.

Comment: Check maxcdns redirect: https://postimg.org/image/fw37kobmr/

They also use https and www but have only one redirect.

Can you help with the redirect code?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's possible using a form of IF statement booleans, in the htaccess, but really, if it's not something you can do easily the benefit of it is extremely light, so inefficient to spend much time messing around with it. . . .